# Convert LONGTEXT records storing IPv4/6 addresses to INT(10) UNSIGNED and BINARY(16)

Tags: mysql

I have a table on my application storing tens of thousands of events (such as when a user logs in) and the number is growing. Each event records the IP address which can be either IPv4/6. This is not elegant design nor efficient for storing records, or indexing.

IPv4 should be stored as `INT(10) UNSIGNED` and IPv6 as `BINARY(16)` (am I right?). I want to create two new columns e.g. `ipv4` and `ipv6` and populate them with either `NULL` or an IPv4/6 address. Currently, all IP addresses are stored in a column called `event_meta` as a `longtext`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself after creating the two columns `ipv4` and `ipv6` described above and the solution is more efficient than Ulrich's approach.

**Query:**

`UPDATE user_activity
SET ipv4 = CASE
    WHEN event_meta LIKE "%.%" THEN INET_ATON(event_meta)
    ELSE NULL
END,
    ipv6 = CASE
    WHEN event_meta LIKE "%:%" THEN INET6_ATON(event_meta)
    ELSE NULL
END;`

**This took 1.93s, or about 35,000 rows per second.** I used the `LIKE` operator with wildcards `.` and `:`. Regex matching might make this fast for other readers with many more rows than my 69,000 at present, but this isn't always supported for some MySQL versions.

Answer (score 0):

You question "... should be stored as ... am I right?" is hard to answer, but probably not. The error here is in the question itself, in particular that you don't specify the requirements that you have for the storage of these values. In some cases, a packed, binary representation (8 octets for IPv4, 16 for IPv8) is the best, in other cases, the usual textual representations are better. Which case you have depends on your (unknown) requirements.

Now, concerning this particular case, here's what I would do as a sane default:

1. Convert IPv4 to IPv6. There is an unambiguous, reversible mapping from IPv4 to IPv6, so every IPv4 address has exactly one representation in the IPv6 numberspace.
2. Format the IP addresses as text. RFC 4291 defines this format, see the Wikipedia page as a start.

What you get is a single column with at most 39 characters. This is human-readable, for diagnostics and maintenance tasks. Also, it can be efficiently indexed, if that's even a concern with just a few thousand entries.

Comment: Motivation is sorting times. While 60k records is okay, this number is growing fast and in a few months, sorting millions of events would add overhead to a query when it could be done faster using other data structures. Thank you for the strategy though but I want a method to conform to the standard data structure (int(10) unsigned and binary(16)) across the application used in other tables, for the sake of JOINs in the future if need be, as one use-case). I also think I need to store an extra byte with a text column which I don't need with my data structures, but maybe I'm wrong.